# Refreshing page in Meteor with iron:router always clears route

Tags: javascript, meteor, reload, iron-router, page-refresh

I have a Meteor app that I've developed using the iron:router package.  I know my users will have the tendency to reload the page because everybody loves to do that occasionally.

My problem is that every time the page is reloaded it goes back to the home page of my Meteor app.

Is there a way make the app stay on the route it was on when the page is reloaded?

Here is my routes code:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout', // Defines the layout template
  loadingTemplate: 'loading' // Defines the loading template
});

// Add the dataNotFound plugin, which is responsible for
// rendering the dataNotFound template if your RouteController
// data function returns a false value
Router.plugin('dataNotFound', {
  notFoundTemplate: 'dataNotFound'
});

Router.route('/', {
  name: 'home',
  template: 'home'
});

Router.route('/signup');
Router.route('/login');
Router.route('/recoverpassword');
Router.route('/resetpassword');
```

Here is everything related to layout:

```
<template name="layout">
  {{> navigation}}
  {{> yield}}
  {{> footer}}
</template>

<head>
  <title>Ecclesia.Life</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Dropdown menu script -->
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>   

<template name="navigation">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{pathFor route='home'}}">Ecclesia.Life</a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 1px;">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="{{pathFor route='home'}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Home</a></li>
                <li><a id="qrScanner" href="#" onclick="inDevelopment();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-qrcode"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;QR Scanner</a></li>
                <script>
                    $('#qrScanner').click(function() {
                        alert("Still in in development");
                    });
                </script>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                {{#if currentUser}}
                    {{#if isInRole 'admin'}}
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Maintenance <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/manageusers"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Manage Users</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="/addqrpage"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Add QR Page</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    {{/if}}
                    <li><a href="/@{{currentUser.username}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{currentUser.profile.firstName}}&nbsp;{{currentUser.profile.lastName}}</a></li>
                    <li><a id="logout" href="{{pathFor route='login'}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Log out</a></li>
                {{else}}
                    <li><a href="{{pathFor route='login'}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Log in</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{pathFor route='signup'}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sign up</a></li>
                {{/if}}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

```
<template name="footer">
    <footer class="footer footer-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <hr />
            <p class="text-muted">Copyright &copy; Ecclesia.Life, 2015.</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</template>
```

Comment: this sounds like rather unusual behavior. can you share some code?

Comment: I've just included my routes code

Comment: And on what url are you on when reloading brings it back to home?

Comment: All of them: /signup, /login etc.

Comment: I am commenting from phone, so I cant try it out. Will do it tomorrow if it wont be solved by then. It is not supposed to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have put together small test [repo](https://github.com/martunta/routeTest) and everything works perfectly. Try it out, and maybe you will spot difference in your code. If it still does not work, post more code (template definitions at least) and in what folders you have your files. Also what packages you have installed.

Comment: Thanks for taking effort to make that but I don't see an issue in anything I've done.  Here's a list of my packages:  accounts-password
iron:router
sacha:spin
steeve:jquery-qrcode
hitchcott:qr-scanner
twbs:bootstrap
bootswatch:cosmo
alanning:roles
reactive-var

Comment: I have all my templates in /client/templates, while my head and body html is just in /client.  My routes are in /lib

Comment: But if you run my repo on your computer, then refresh works without breaking routes?

Comment: Well I guess I'll have to search for my own code to find out what's causing it to go straight to home page on refresh (this app has gotten pretty big).

Thanks for the answer, didn't know it automatically stays on the right route for refresh.

Comment: Routes are meant to be stored in the lib folder of my project right?

Comment: Yes, that is preferred setup

Comment: Ah man, still searching for what is causing this.  I can't even manually navigate to a page without it being redirected to the home page...

Comment: Try copy of application and start removing code. Remove everything except one route and one or two templates. If it still does not work then compare it line by line with working example. If it works, then start adding things vack until it stops working

Comment: It has something to do with the home template.  The body and head of my code are basically empty and I have a layout template.  Is that how it should be?

Comment: Try to remove all code related to layout template, and see what happens. It is not mandatory

Comment: I keep all my templates in their own file, could that be causing the problem?

Comment: No, should not be the problem.

Comment: Ah!!  I still can't find the solution to this :/  It works without a layout template but I really need the layout template for other features in the app...

Comment: Well, post everything related to layout somewhere and I will take a look

Comment: I've added an edit to my problem, let me know if you need more information somewhere

Comment: Try to move all your head and body tags within kayout template. Basically if you have layout template then not a single piece of html should be outside template tags

Comment: I have incorporated your code into my test repo. you can see the new version. it just works :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102283/discussion-between-barry-doyle-and-martins-untals).

Comment: @Barry, did you find the cause and solution for your issue?  I have the same problem here...

Comment: Yeah I had some random function causing it to always redirect to the home route.